# Bold boxplot labels in R

Tags: r, label, boxplot

Does anybody know how to embolden the `x` and `y` axis labels ("Single sample" and "Value axis") in an R boxplot?

This is what my boxplot looks like:
[image: http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/331/23807704.png]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using this example data:

```
dat <- data.frame(values = c(rnorm(100, mean = 1), rnorm(100, mean = 3),
                             rnorm(100, mean = 4, sd = 3)),
                  groups = factor(rep(c("aaa","bbb","ccc"), each = 100)))
```

There are several ways. One is to use `?plotmath` functionality and the `plotmath` "function" `bold()` in an expression:

```
boxplot(values ~ groups, data = dat,
        ylab = expression(bold(Value~axis)),
        xlab = expression(bold(Single~sample)))
```

or, similarly

```
boxplot(values ~ groups, data = dat,
        ylab = expression(bold("Value axis")),
        xlab = expression(bold("Single sample")))
```

Another way is to leave the titles off the plot and then add them with the `title()` function using the bold font:

```
boxplot(values ~ groups, data = dat)
title(ylab = "Value axis", xlab = "Single sample", font.lab = 2)
```

We need graphical parameter `font.lab` as this is the parameter that controls the axis labels. Read the entries in `?par` for more info.